# How to add random number in each cell of a column?

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I am sure this is a pretty naive question, but I have never done this before, so please bear with me. I have an Excel sheet with multiple columns. For one of the column, I have to add a random number in each cell of that column.

E.g.

```
Col1 Col2

45    12
34    34
12    12
56    78
78    30
```

Now In the second column, I have to add something random, say between 0 to 10. **I cannot put completely random values in the second column, as all I want is a slight deviation from the already existing values.**

I know how to generate random numbers, using `RAND()` or `RANDBETWEEN()`. I also know that I can convert it to integer using `ROUNDUP()` and then `SUM()` it up. But when I try to do it using formula, it gives me circular reference warning, which is correct.

Can someone help with this? Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: notwithstanding my answer......is this a "one-off" addition of a random amount?.....if you use RAND() or similar then the random value will change every time the worksheet re-calculates, do you want that?

Comment: @barry: yes, I know that and that is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't reference B2 **within** cell B2 without getting a circular reference. Unless you want to "hardcode" the value for each cell, e.g. in B2 `=12+RAND()`, in B3 `=34+RAND()`....I suggest you use a third column with this formula or similar in C2 copied down

`=B2+RAND()`

Comment: I have already solved the problem with same technique. Thanks for the response, though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (for the second column):

```
=A2-5+RANDBETWEEN(1,10)
```

The -5 is added if you want both smaller and larger then the number in the first column

Comment: this will cause circular ref problem, i guess.

Comment: ohh ok, but as I said, **the number cannot be completely random**, it has to be some deviation of the original value.

Comment: Maybe a good idea to test the solution, couse thats exactly what this formula does, if cell 1 is 20, cell 2 will be between 15 and 25....